# Sharepoint List - create item in with lookup values

Tags: json, sharepoint, graph

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

explains how to create a JSON POST for a "create item" in a simple list.

I am looking for an example with lookup columns -- as cut and past of "get response" fails for list fields definition.

e.g.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "Title": "2020-of-003",
        "F8_LOOKUP": [
            {
                "LookupId": 6,
                "LookupValue": "Alfred Anders"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just concat LookupId to your field-name and add odata.type for multi lookup
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/2991#issuecomment-443347657

```
POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
```

multi lookup:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "From graph",
    "fieldnameLookupId@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)",
    "fieldnameLookupId": [1,2]
  }
}
```

lookup:

```
{
  "fields": {
    "Title": "From graph",
    "fieldnameLookupId": 1
  }
}
```